# FFMPEG Convert video to images

Tags: ffmpeg

when I use ffmpeg to convert video to images there's one problem,the total number of pictures is not equal to the number of frames.

first, I used ffprobe cmd to get the total number of frames：

```
 ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 in.mp4
```

and got the number is 278

then,I used ffmpeg cmd to convert video to images:

```
ffmpeg -i 'in.mp4' -f image2 -qscale:v 2 'out_%05d.png'
```

but I got 281 pictures.

I checked out the ffmpeg's documentation but found nothing about this

so how can I solve this problem

Comment: please can you share the output of both commands?

Comment: Try `-vsync passthrough`